# rsync only files younger than xy days

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I am using `rsync` to copy photos form our satellite servers into main server. So the script doing it is basically connecting from PC to PC and executing `rsync`.

I have been trying to use find to determine files younger than xy days (it will be days, but number can vary). Specifing the files with `--files-from=<()` BUT the command `find /var/dav/davserver/ -mtime -3 -type f -exec basename {} \;` is on some machines very very slow, and even makes rsync to timeout. Also they are servers, so running this command every few minutes would cost too much processor power that I don't want to take away.

The second aproach was to take advantage of the way we are storing those files, under `/var/dav/davserver/year/month/day/` directory. However as I started to work on it, I have realized that I need to write quite a some code do take care of end of months and years, even more that number of days is not fixed (it can be more than 31 days, thus this scrip could need to run through several months).

So I was wondering if there is not some easier way how to achieve this without killing source PCs processor or write a whole new library to take care of all month/year ends?

---

**EDIT:**

I have prepared script that generates paths to files for me. What I did, is that I left handling end of months/year for `date`..

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE_now=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
DATE_end=`date -d "-$1 days" +"%Y-%m-%d"`

echo "Date now: $DATE_now | Date end: $DATE_end"

start_d=`date +%s`
end_d=`date -d "-$1 days" +%s`

synced_day=$DATE_now
synced_day_s=$start_d
daycount=1

echo "" > /tmp/$2_paths

while [ $synced_day_s -ge $end_d ]; do
    DAY=$(date -d "$synced_day" '+%d')
    MONTH=$(date -d "$synced_day" '+%m')
    YEAR=$(date -d "$synced_day" '+%Y')

    SYNC_DIR="/var/dav/davserver/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/**"
    echo "Adding day ($synced_day) directory: \"$SYNC_DIR\" to synced paths | Day: $daycount"
    echo $SYNC_DIR >> /tmp/$2_paths

    synced_day=$(date -d "$synced_day -1 days" +"%Y-%m-%d")
    synced_day_s=$(date -d "$synced_day" +%s)
    daycount=$((daycount+1))
done
```

and counting down days using it, than just extract needed info. This script gives me a list of directories to rsync:

```
rrr@rRr-kali:~/bash_devel$ bash date_extract.sh 8 Z00163
Date now: 2017-06-29 | Date end: 2017-06-21
Adding day (2017-06-29) directory: "/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/29/**" to synced paths | Day: 1
Adding day (2017-06-28) directory: "/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/28/**" to synced paths | Day: 2
Adding day (2017-06-27) directory: "/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/27/**" to synced paths | Day: 3
Adding day (2017-06-26) directory: "/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/26/**" to synced paths | Day: 4
Adding day (2017-06-25) directory: "/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/25/**" to synced paths | Day: 5
Adding day (2017-06-24) directory: "/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/24/**" to synced paths | Day: 6
Adding day (2017-06-23) directory: "/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/23/**" to synced paths | Day: 7
Adding day (2017-06-22) directory: "/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/22/**" to synced paths | Day: 8
rrr@rRr-kali:~/bash_devel$ cat /tmp/Z00163_paths 

/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/29/**
/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/28/**
/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/27/**
/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/26/**
/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/25/**
/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/24/**
/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/23/**
/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/22/**
rrr@rRr-kali:~/bash_devel$
```

However, now is my problem to use this list, I have been trying to use many combination of `--include` and `--exclude` commands with both `--include-files` and `--include-from` BUT I am getting only 2 results: either everything is being rsynced, or nothing.

Comment: Rsync has an `--ignore-existing` option, so it only copies new files.

Comment: yes but on satellite servers there might be data about 3 years old (in some cases). however I want to hold only data that are like 30 days old, on main server.

Comment: Can you run your `find` command first, piped to a file, and only then start the `rsync` command? Or even piped into `rsync`. Just not in a subshell.

Comment: But if you do want to calculate which of your year/month/day folders are in scope, that's a problem that solutions exist for. I'm not sure of a Bash solution but it would be easy in Python.

Comment: I have updated topic with actuall progress.

Comment: Are you trying to copy the complete ``/var/dav/davserver/2017/06/29/`` dir, or do you wish to exclude some files?

Comment: Complete directory. But more of those.

Comment: Then, you don't need to use ``dir/**``, just say ``rsync -avrz foo:src/bar /data/dest``, for each ``bar`` in directory list generated (see my answer).

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood you. I mean content of those two directories (they have another subdirectories and files in them)

Comment: Then just use the ``-r`` (recursive copy) flag.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have files ordered by date (in directories), it's easy and efficient to just `rsync` those directories:

```
#!/bin/bash
maxage="45"  # in days, from today
for ((d=0; d<=maxage; d++)); do
    dir="/var/dav/davserver/$(date -d "-$d day" +"%Y/%m/%d")"
    rsync -avrz server:"$dir" localdir
done
```

We're using `date` to calculate `today - x days` and iterate over all days from `0` to your `maxage`.

Edit: use arithmetic `for` loop instead of iterating over GNU `seq` range.

Comment: yes, that is the solution, however, the problem is that I wanted rsync to also delete files that were synced yrday and are today out of date

Comment: You could run a similar clean-up script to just delete locally all directories older than ``maxage`` days: ``for d in $(seq "$maxage" "365"); do ...``.

Comment: *grumble* re: `seq` (not part of bash, not POSIX-standardized). `for ((d=0; d<=365; d++)); do ...` is guaranteed to work everywhere bash is, whereas `i=0; while [ "$i" -le 365 ]; do ...; i=$((i + 1)); done` is guaranteed to work on all POSIX shells.

Comment: You're right, @CharlesDuffy. Let's just say I'm GNU-challenged. :) GNU or bust! :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I have solved it with combination of:

Script generating paths according to actual date. Details are presented in my edit of initial post. It simply uses `date` to go through previous days and manage month and year ends. And generate paths from those dates. However radomir's solution is simplier, so I will use it. (Its basically same as I did, just simplier way to write it down).

than I have used combination of `--include-files=/tmp/files_list` and `-r` a.k.a. `--recursive` argument to use this list of paths properly.
(It was copying only empty directories without `-r`. And everything or nothing if I have used `--include-from` instead of `--include-files`)

Final rsync command is:

```
rsync --timeout=300 -Sazrv --force --delete --numeric-ids --files-from=/tmp/date_paths app_core@172.23.160.1:/var/dav/davserver/ /data/snapshots/
```

However this solution is not deleting old files on my side, despite `--delete` argument. Will probably need to make an extra script for it.

Comment: No need for a temp file (and you avoid exposure to symlink attacks) if you use a process substitution to generate the list. (`--from0 --files-from=<(find "$path" -mtime -7 -print0`). Or, at minimum, use `mktemp` to generate a unique tempfile name -- that way an attacker can't create a symlink in `/tmp` (which is, after all, a world-writable directory) to a file they want you to delete.